# Docker tomcat edit expanded war files

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, war

I am using docker to deploy a tomcat container running a third party `war` file.

My `Dockerfile` looks something like this

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre8

ADD my.war ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/my.war
```

When I run the container tomcat expands my `war` at runtime and I can happily access my app at `http://my.ip.addr:8080/mywar/`.

However my problem is that I want to edit a couple of the config files within the `war`. I don't really want to unpack and repack the `war` file as that seems messy and hard to maintain.

I was hoping to be able to tell tomcat to expand the `war` as part of my `RUN` steps and then use `ADD` to put in my custom files but I can't seem to find a way of doing this. The war only gets expanded when the `CMD` executes and then I can't edit the files after that.

Comment: connect with `docker exec -it container_id bash` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec then modify your files, then `exit` to leave the container, and then commit your modification if needed with `docker commit` see http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit

Comment: That does not seem ideal as I would have to do those manual steps every time I update the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure exactly how you would achieve it with docker or anything else, as i dont see anyway to ask tomcat to just expand the war before it actually starts. But as per standard practices its not a good idea to explode a war and tweak the contents. It kills the entire purpose of making a war.

Rather you should make changes to the app to read configuration from << TOMCAT_HOME >>/conf.

If you achieve this the only thing you will need to tell Docker is to ADD your configuration file to the containers tomcat conf folder.

Or if it is a must for you to tamper with war file this is what you can do:
Explode the war manually (or by script) on your build machine and instead of adding war directly to the docker image, map the folder. 
Something like this

ADD ./target/app-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.

And then manually add all your files to desired destinations.

ADD login.jsp /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT/Webapps, so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes I agree but the application is packaged by a third party and would prefer not to have to update it every release.

Comment: If thats the case, another approach that you can take is Explode the war manually on your build machine and instead of adding war directly to the docker image, map the folder. Something like this ADD ./target/app-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT. And separately add your config to the image.

Comment: It looks like some things get put in `content` as well as `webapps`. What do I do about those?

Comment: you can add any resource to any folder given that its expolded.  So ones you have done this `ADD ./target/app-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT`, you can say `ADD login.jsp /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT/Webapps`, so on and so forth.

Comment: I agree that the "whats in the container" should remain untouched....and the (code) in the container should read config values from somewhere else.  Environment-Variables is another option. Extra thinking: If you deploy to Cloud / (Azure is my most experience), EVs is the first-level way to do this.  Secret volumes is another.  (see link later in this comment).  Regardless, tweaking values after the fact .. is the less preferred way IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

How about unzipping your war manually, before starting tomcat?

```
ADD my.war /tmp/my.war 
RUN unzip /tmp/my.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mywar

# Edit config files

# Now you can start tomcat...
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: There seems to be some content which is extracted outside of the `webapps` directory, `content` for example. I'm not sure how to extract this to the correct place.

Comment: Hmmm... Is this Tomcat 7 related? (I can't find a "content" dir on my Tomcat 8). Did you try whether my approach works nevertheless? Or: Which parts are missing if you unzip manually?

Comment: Your approach works but then the application cannot find its config (which it expects to find in `content`). When unzipping manually I can find the config files which end up in `content` but I can't tell how they know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Run command to start the tomcat container and then immediately stop it. This will cause the war to be expanded and then you can go ahead and modify the config files.

Ex:

```
RUN Start_tomcat.sh && \
    stop_tomcat.sh && \
    edit_1_config_file.sh && \
    edit_2_config_file.sh
```

Note: The you need to do all the steps in one run command. As Docker build will take each command and run it on the image generated from the previous command and commit. And incase of services, depending on a service that has been started in the previous RUN command will not work.

Comment: I did try this but the start tomcat script (in my case `catalina.sh start`) just sits running forever and never exits to run the stop script.

Comment: How did you install tomcat? if you installed it through a package manager, you should have a /etc/init.d/tomcat start or service tomcat start that should start it in the background.. Also take a look at this https://www.liferay.com/web/brett.swaim/blog/-/blogs/sample-tomcat-startup-scripts, it seems you can call $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh to startup tomcat.

Comment: I'm using the official docker tomcat7 image.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `RUN` instruction which launches the server in the background, gives it a few seconds then exits i.e.

```
RUN bash -c "catalina.sh start; sleep 5; catalina.sh stop;"
```

You will need to give it long enough to expand the war file.

Comment: I tried this, the `catalina.sh start` command just hangs and never exits.

Comment: That's a different problem - catalina.sh start should fork. I did test this.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing catalina.sh run and catalina.sh start?

Comment: Aha! You might have cracked it there. Your solution is not what I would call neat but I think it's the best I'm going to get.

Comment: this works! i did this then moved over a context.xml. Image booted perfectly

Comment: How did you know 5 seconds? Is there a benchmark or something similar?