# How to I externalize my configuration for my spring-boot war application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot war application that is packaged using Maven, and I need to deploy it as docker image. Now I am done with creating docker image, my current problem is how do I pass external configuration? I am not running my spring-boot application as java -jar myapp.war. The person responsible for deploying this image will need to pass the path of the configuration file to docker image.

Comment: This person will have to mount the configuration file. Eg. `docker run -v "$PWD/config:/etc/app/config:ro" your/image`

Comment: You can use environment variables to pass configuration. It doesn't have to be a file.

Comment: So I understand that person will need to mount the drive where configuration will be, but how I do marry these external configurations with spring? Here is my docker file content                                                                                   From tomcat:9-jre11
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./email-adapter-thin-app/target/XXXX-email-adapter-.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]

Comment: Found something similar to what I was looking - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760989/docker-tomcat-edit-expanded-war-files

Comment: Found something similar to what I was looking - link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760989/docker-tomcat-edit-expanded-war-files>

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for posterity. I ended up using the image in Docker Compose at that time and passed values as shown below.

Docker-Compose[image]

Additionally used .env file for passing database configurations.

```
POSTGRESQL_USER=evops
POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD=**
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=**
POSTGRESQL_SERVER_PORT=5432
POSTGRESQL_SERVER_HOST=operations-db
```